# sqoop query failing to import table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to execute below sqoop import.

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP;database=db_name' --username xxx --password xxx --table xxx --hive-import --hive-table amit_hive --target-dir /user/hive/amitesh123 -m 1.
```

I have to import a DB table directly to the desired location. as per my understanding goes, above sqoop command line syntax is correctly written. But on executing it, I am get following error:-

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=xxx, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/hive/amitesh123":hive:hdfs:drwx
```

Somebody informed me that we have to mention the HIVE database name as well with the above sqoop commands,is that true?,if yes, can someone help me with the parameter that I have use? As per my knowledge goes, we just need to mention the --table to bring the table from DB to HIVE table. please suggest

To test further, I created a new folder , and gave 777 rights to it, still I am getting same error. I have now added the HIVE DB.HIVEtable name with --hive-table, so now the new sqoop import is as follows::

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://server-IP;database=db_name' --username xxx --password xxx --table xxx --hive-import --hive-table amitesh_db.amit_hive   --target-dir  /amitesh012345/amitesh -m 1.
```

However, the permission denied error still there...

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1486315054135_2834 failed with state FAILED due to: Job setup failed : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=xxx, access=WRITE, inode="/amitesh012345/amitesh/_temporary/1":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1704)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1687)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:983)        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3002)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2970)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1061)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobSetup(CommitterEventHandler.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=at732615, access=WRITE, inode="/amitesh012345/amitesh/_temporary/1":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1704)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1687)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:983)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:55
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3000)
        ... 13 more
17/03/14 05:23:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 2
        Job Counters
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
17/03/14 05:23:38 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
17/03/14 05:23:38 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 24.4698 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
17/03/14 05:23:38 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
17/03/14 05:23:38 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
17/03/14 05:23:38 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

2nd full stacktrace

+++++++++++++

```
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/03/14 05:38:02 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6_IBM_27
17/03/14 05:38:02 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/03/14 05:38:02 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
17/03/14 05:38:02 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
17/03/14 05:38:02 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/03/14 05:38:02 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:path_to/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:path_to/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/03/14 05:38:03 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [T_VND] AS t WHERE 1=0
17/03/14 05:38:03 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is path_to/hadoop
Note: path_to/T_VND.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/03/14 05:38:04 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: path_to/T_VND.jar
17/03/14 05:38:04 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of T_VND
17/03/14 05:38:05 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://xxxxxx/
17/03/14 05:38:05 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxxxx/server-IP:port
17/03/14 05:38:06 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/03/14 05:38:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
17/03/14 05:38:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1486315054135_2836
17/03/14 05:38:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1486315054135_2836
17/03/14 05:38:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://xxxxxx/server-IP:port/proxy/application_1486315054135_2836/
17/03/14 05:38:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1486315054135_2836
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=FAILED. Redirecting to job history server
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1486315054135_2836 running in uber mode : false
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 100%
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1486315054135_2836 failed with state FAILED due to:
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: The MapReduce job has already been retired. Performance
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: counters are unavailable. To get this information,
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: you will need to enable the completed job store on
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: the jobtracker with:
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active = true
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours = 1
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: A jobtracker restart is required for these settings
17/03/14 05:38:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: to take effect.
17/03/14 05:38:13 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

Comment: Sqoop after importing data to the `--target-dir`, it loads the data into Hive table. So the user running the sqoop command must have permissions for the target drectory and hive warehouse directory. In your first command, sqoop does not have access to `--target-dir` itself. Can you post the stacktrace of second command?

Comment: The user `at732615` does not have `write` access for `--target-dir`.

Comment: There is one thing I wanted to bring in to your notice, in the 2nd command, /amitesh012345/amitesh, "amitesh" didn't existed, so, I removed that from the command, and this time the error is different.  2nd full stacktrace edited in original post.Pardon me for my mistake.

Comment: please close the thread, I got the issue resolved. I simply removed "/" from amitesh012345, that resolved th eissue. It made sense, as earlier, I was using /amitesh012345 as my --target-dir, so when I ran the "hadoop fs -ls /", I didn't find amitesh012345 there. Thank you all for your help and time